# Stop label from resetting when closing a form visual basic

Tags: vb.net

In visual basic I have a label set to increment every time a button is clicked. However when I close and reopen the form the label goes back to default value. Is there a way to keep this label the same it was before I closed the form? Thanks

Comment: There are of course *many* ways to save data.  You'd consider a Setting in this case.  Project + Properties, Settings tab.

Answer (score 0):

When you close the form instance every local object kept by the form is disposed (destroyed). When you show again the form a new instance of the form class is created but the objects are all initialized to their default values. So you have lost your current value.

A possible workaround is to have a Shared variable inside the form class that keeps the count.
Shared variables are not destroyed with the class instance but are available for every instance of the class with their current value

You use this value to initialize your label in the form constructor with the current value of your clicks

```
Public Class Form1
   Private Shared clickCount As Integer

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        myLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(clickCount)
    End Sub

    ' you could also use Form1_Load event if you prefer
    ' Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    '    Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(clicksCount)
    ' End Sub


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        clicksCount += 1
        myLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(clicksCount)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Keep in mind that this approach use the same variable (`clickCount`) for every instance of Form1 you create.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I was thinking of another way but is there a event handler for when you open a form?

Comment: Form_Load (you could use that either for the same purpose)